# Invalid attempt to call HasRows when reader is closed

Tags: c#, sql

I have this problem: Invalid attempt to call HasRows when reader is closed.
I have tried alot; removing connection close line, closing the connection in the end. but having same issue. I can't get whats wrong with my code.

```
try
{
    con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TextItConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    using (con)
    {
        con.Open();
        Library.writeErrorLog("connection build and open");
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        using (cmd)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "Select [name] From [dbo].[Users]";
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            using (reader)
            {
                user.dt.Load(reader);
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Library.writeErrorLog(reader.GetString(0));
                    }
                }
                else
                    Library.writeErrorLog("no rows");
                reader.Close();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    //SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("Select [name] From [dbo].[Users]", con);
    //adap.Fill(user.dt);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Library.writeErrorLog(ex);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you show method user.dt.Load()?

Comment: I assume that `user.dt` returns a `DataTable`. You know that `DataTable.Load(reader)` will consumeall recorda of the resultset and advances the reader to the next set? I'm asking because you are using `HasRows` **after** you've already used `DataTable.Load`. Side-note: you don't need to use `reader.Close` or `con.Close` if you use the `using`-statement.

Comment: Looking at the reference source of [DataTable.Load](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,a907a83034e99786) you could clearly see that the DataReader is closed before exiting from the method.

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan user is my class, dt is DataTable and load is its builtin function to load data in dataTbales

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `user.dt` returns a `DataTable`. You know that [`DataTable.Load(reader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb(v=vs.110).aspx) will consume all records of the resultset and advances the reader to the next set? I'm asking because you are using `HasRows` **after** you've already used `DataTable.Load`.

As [Steve has commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656737/invalid-attempt-to-call-hasrows-when-reader-is-closed#comment62792717_37656737)

> Looking at the reference source of [`DataTable.Load`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,7dbafcd71c803dc0,references) you could clearly
>   see that the `DataReader` is closed before exiting from the method.

So if there is no other resultset(f.e. `SELECT * FROM T1;SELECT* from T2`) the reader will be closed at the end of `Load` which will cause the exception if you try to use `SqlDataReader.HasRows`.

I'd call this a **lack of documentation** since it's mentioned nowhere on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb(v=vs.110).aspx).

So either use

1. `reader.Read` and `reader.GetString` in a loop and add it to the `DataTable` manually,
2. use `DataTable.Load` and loop the table afterwards or
3. use `SqlDataAdapter.Fill(table)`:

1) `while` loop and manually filling the table

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if(reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string name = reader.GetString(0);
            user.dt.Rows.Add(name);
            Library.writeErrorLog(name);
        }
    }
    else
        Library.writeErrorLog("no rows");
}
```

2)   requires two loops, one in `DataTable.Load` and the `foreach`

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if(reader.HasRows)
    {
        user.dt.Load(reader); // all records added
        foreach(DataRow row in user.dt.Rows)
        {
            string name = row.Field<string>(0);
            Library.writeErrorLog(name);
        }
    }
    else
        Library.writeErrorLog("no rows");
}
```

3) another option is to use a `SqlDataAdapter` and it's `Fill(dataTable)` method:

```
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    da.Fill(user.dt);
    if (user.dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in user.dt.Rows)
        {
            string name = row.Field<string>(0);
            Library.writeErrorLog(name);
        }
    }
    else
        Library.writeErrorLog("no rows");
}
```

---

Side-note: you don't need to use `reader.Close` or `con.Close` if you use the `using`-statement.

Comment: Thank you @Tim it works. Now i know where i was wrong. Yeah its a silly mistake (Lack of documentation). Thankyou for helping me.

Comment: @MuhammadTauseen: you're welcome. Note that i've added a third approach using `SqlDataAdapter.Fill`. Then you don't need the reader at all. Note that you don't even need to open/close the connection if you use `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` since that is done automatically (but it doesn't hurt to do it either).

Comment: oh great. Thanks again. I am having another problem. The above code is my windows service. i want to load data from my windows service to the web page. after loading the data to the DataTable dt, I'm calling the function from Default.aspx.cs file to load in the gridview
In Default.aspx.cs file
`GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();`

Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @MuhammadTauseen: i don't understand how the windows service and the web application are related. You can't and you should not need to access the web-app from the windows-service. The same is true for the opposite way. A windows service could be used to update the database and the web-app to read from the database and display the result. Then you have an indirect relation between both.

Comment: Doing work on a big project. Its data is updated every minute. So I am creating a windows service that will run after every minute and update the GridView on webPage

Comment: @MuhammadTauseen: you cannot update a GridView from a windows-service. If the data is updated you should use a [`Timer`-control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404(v=vs.100).aspx)(f.e. ASP.NET Ajax) and reload the GridView in the `Tick`-event. Since you update the database from the windows-service you'll always get the latest version in the `GridView`.

Comment: Okay Thanks for your guidance and help

Comment: I didnt want to update database from windows service. I only need to run a query and get the data from database and that data should be shown on the webpage @Tim